# How can we loop through items that are coordinates, load each into a Google Maps page, and grab an element from each page?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm testing the code below, which should loop through items in a column of a dataframe, load each into Google Maps, and grab a 'title' from each page. I want to push the result into a column in a dataframe (df_fin['my_place'] = driver.title).

The problem that I am noticing is that the first record works perfectly fine, but no subsequent items work. I'm guessing something is wrong with the page refresh, or maybe the click event, but I don't know for sure what's going on here.

```
import pandas as pd
df_fin = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\df_fin.csv')

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\TryMe\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

i = 1

for item in df_fin['place']:
    try:
        driver.get(item)
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
        main_canvas = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='canvas']")))
        size = main_canvas.size
        w, h = size['width'], size['height']
        new_w = w/2
        new_h = h/2
        ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(new_h, new_h).pause(5).perform()
        time.sleep(2)
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[name()='canvas']"))).click()
        print(driver.title)
        df_fin['my_place'] = driver.title
    except:
        df_fin['my_place'] = 'OTHER'

    i = i + 1
    print(i)

df_fin.head(10)
```

Here is a sample of what's in my dataframe.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/@42.33988,-71.10409,18z
https://www.google.com/maps/@39.73914,-75.54937,18z
https://www.google.com/maps/@44.4995,-88.05496,18z
https://www.google.com/maps/@44.50235,-88.06322,18z
https://www.google.com/maps/@40.82265,-73.40959,18z
```

Finally, in the image below, you can see that 'title' is 'Rod Laver Arena'. That's what I'm trying to get.

[image]

Comment: I did try this and I am getting not all 5, but 2 titles. also if you observe, there's an issue with the co-ordinates, I would suggest to have those Google map URL which has something in middle, cause for few of your URLS, they don't have something in middle, even manual click in the middle did not do much.

Comment: I noticed that middle-behavior too. I cleared the browser cache and it seems to be working now. Thanks. One more quick question. How did you find the XPATH? I hit F12 and searched around for it but didn't see anything in the code behind the page.

Comment: If you are asking `//*[name()='canvas']` about this, basically canvas are special type of element, so write this in console //*[name()='canvas'], and you should be good to go with that, I don't think you can generate them from dev tools. it wouldn't locate.

Comment: Why not query OSM with [geopy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.geocoders)?

Comment: @  RJ Adriaansen, that seems to do exactly what I need! Thanks for showing this to me!!
@   cruisepandey, thanks for sharing your solution. I learned a couple new skills today!!